# How do I load hyperv_fb at start up with Zesty 17.04

Tags: boot, video, display-resolution, hyper-v

I recently DL zesty and installed in Win10 Hyper-V and added virtual video card. I also installed linux-image-extra-virtual. When I followed the canonical instructions for adding a hyperv_fb: resolution and updated grub, the video resolution does not change after rebooting. Using lsmod shows lots of hyperv items loaded, but not hyperf_fb.

How do I (do I need to?) get the hyperv_fb/linux-image-extra-virtual component loaded during boot?

Comment: "the canonical instructions" which are those?

Comment: There are lots of places that have the same instructions. Here is one link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2014/09/19/changing-ubuntu-screen-resolution-in-a-hyper-v-vm/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. I manually added the Linux extensions by doing the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the file, add:

```
linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Reboot.

I also removed the virtual video card from the Hyper-V configuration settings.